# huggingface model.push_to_hub(peft_model_id) NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-hub

I am trying to push a model to huggingface hub. My huggingface id is `aben118` and the model name is `test` that I want to upload.

```
peft_model_id = "aben118/test"
model.push_to_hub(peft_model_id)
```

I face the following error and cannot figure out why.

> NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/u/hys4qm/.conda/envs/whisper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub-0.20.3-py3.8.egg/huggingface_hub/templates/modelcard_template.md'

Note: I can successfully push using colab notebook. The script I am running is a .py file.

Note: In my `/u/hys4qm/.conda/envs/whisper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/` folder I can see that I don't have any `huggingface_hub-0.20.3-py3.8.egg` folder, although I installed through `pip3 install --upgrade huggingface_hub`

Answer (score 0):

Doing `conda install -c conda-forge huggingface_hub` worked